# Interpolate data from the given time series and plot the scatter plot with equation in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have a time series of more than 2500 points. I also have observed data set but it is not continuous. I want to use the observed data set and find out the modeled data from the time series data. After the modeled data has been found out for the same time I want to plot the correlation plot and display the equation and coefficient of correlation on the plot.

The sample time series can be found on the following link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxg0g1h7vbhxp3z/33010G10.csv

The observed data is as follows:

```
260.323 25.170
267.316 25.520
274.313 24.950
281.333 25.140
288.326 24.130
295.319 19.540
302.330 10.280
309.323 17.340
317.326 18.300
323.323 11.280
329.355 12.450
337.333 9.050
351.323 14.620
364.389 16.350
372.368 19.400
379.382 10.980
393.382 14.260
414.377 11.640
421.382 10.660
428.378 3.950
435.382 18.950
442.378 18.180
449.378 20.570
456.368 18.400
463.375 11.770
470.382 18.130
477.372 18.370
484.368 21.310
491.375 24.200
498.378 24.070
505.382 18.600
512.389 24.670
526.392 28.310
533.406 28.310
540.399 28.700
547.375 28.400
554.389 27.050
```

Please let me know how can I efficiently arrange the dataset so that I could repeat this for several other locations. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `textbox` function in package 'plotrix'. For plotting a regression line this should suffice

```
 plot(dat$Date,dat$Minimum)
 abline(coef(lm(Minimum~Date, data=dat)))
```

You will need to describe what you mean by "arrange the dataset so that I could repeat this for several other locations."